# Ask the id of another agent when are together and check it is not repeated

Tags: netlogo

Walkers (dynamic) moves between nodes connecting links. Some nodes have events (static) agents. I would like to save the id's of those events in a walker-own list (eve-ids). Now I am doing:

```
move-to n ; n is a next node
if any? events-here [ 
   let event-x events-here
   set eve-ids lput ([who] of event-x) eve-ids 
]
```

This lines write the `event` breed id into `eve-ids`, but I would like to know that is not a repeated event already found by the walker (i.e. only write event id's the first time they are found).

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to approach this.  Both recognize that `events-here` produces an agentset, so `[who] of event-x` yields a list of event agents.  Other things being equal, therefore, `eve-ids` will be a list of lists of agent who numbers.

One approach is to make the list of lists into a simple list and then use `remove-duplicates` to weed out any duplicate events.  In NetLogo v.5.3, the first step could be done using `reduce` and `sentence` as follows;

```
set eve-ids lput event-x eve-ids   ;add the event-x list to eve-ids
set eve-ids reduce [sentence ?1 ?2] eve-ids  ;collapses eve-ids to a simple list
set eve-ids remove-duplicates eve-ids   ;insures no duplicate events
```

Of course if this is done each time new events are found, then eve-ids will be collapsed to a simple list each time, which then suggests a different approach using `foreach` (although the same might be done with `map`). Here we just append the events in event-x not already found in eve-ids.

```
foreach event-x [
  if not member? ? eve-ids [set eve-ids lput ? eve-ids]
]
```

Now I am going to channel the NetLogo gurus and suggest that unless you really need them, you should not be using who numbers at all, but rather agentsets for your events.  This also makes life simpler as an agentset can not contain duplicates. So, if you do something like:

```
set eve-ids no-turtles  ;start with an empty set of events.
```

in initiating your walker agents.

Then you code could be:

```
move-to n ; n is a next node
if any? events-here [ 
   let event-x events-here
   set eve-ids (turtle-set eve-ids event-x)
]
```

and you will have a growing set of event agents with no duplicates.

Hope this helps - and if you are using NetLogo v6.0, the `reduce` and `foreach` coding will be a bit different as then will use anonymous reporters.

Charles

Comment: Than you very much for your answer. I like the most the third solution which seems to me better. I assume although `eve-ids` is a `walker-own` variable it can contain a turtle set of agents. I thought that could only be done with `breed` in Netlogo.

Comment: Yes, `walker-own` variables can contain an agent set (turtle set), and not all agents in the set need be of the same breed.